# How can I create custom sections in TFS build reports?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild

I know how to add custom [BuildStep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399129.aspx) task; however, it would be nice to create a new section, similar to the **Summary** and **Build Steps** sections.

We are selectively deploying the files on a successful build based on the difference between the workspace and destination environment. We do create an HTML and XML log of the files we move and the files they overwrite. It would be nice to add a section to the build report to display this information.

Something like this:

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/71360b417a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/71360b417a.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Microsoft do not provide any mechanism for extending the build report in VS 2008 or VS 2005.  They are doing heavy changes to the build report for TFS 2010 however and I know that customization of that report has been a much requested feature but I'm not sure what the status is of that yet.

Comment: Thanks Martin. You're a indispensable wealth of TFS knowledge.